# Python - save to different files selected rows and columns from data

Tags: python, split, rows

I have a file.dat of this type but with a lot more data:

```
Apr  1 18:15 [n1_Cam_A_120213_O.fits]: 
4101.77    1. -3.5612   3.561   -0.278635 4.707   6.448     #data1
0.03223    0.  0.05278  0.05278  0.00237  0.4393  0.4125    #error1
4088.9     1. -0.404974 0.405   -0.06538  5.819   0.        #data2
   0.      0.  0.01559  0.01559  0.00277  0.1717  0.        #error2
4116.4     1. -0.225521 0.2255  -0.041111 5.153   0.        #data3
   0.      0.  0.01947  0.01947  0.00368  0.4748  0.        #error3
4120.8     1. -0.382279 0.3823  -0.062194 5.774   0.        #data4
   0.      0.  0.01873  0.01873  0.00311  0.3565  0.        #error4

Apr  1 18:15 [n1_Cam_B_120213_O.fits]: 
4101.767   0.9999  -4.57791  4.578   -0.388646 0.03091 7.499    #data1
0.0293     0.       0.03447  0.03447  0.00243  0.00873 0.07529  #error1
4088.9     1.      -0.211493 0.2115  -0.080003 2.483   0.
   0.      0.       0.01091  0.01091  0.00327  0.1275  0.
4116.4     1.      -0.237161 0.2372  -0.040493 5.502   0.
   0.      0.       0.02052  0.02052  0.00231  0.5069  0.
4120.8     1.      -0.320798 0.3208  -0.108827 2.769   0.
   0.      0.       0.0167   0.0167   0.00404  0.1165  0.
```

first row of each dataset contains a name.fits, even rows contain values, and odd rows (except first) contain errors of the values in the row before. Then comes a blank row and starts again.

What I need is to separate the information into different files in this way:

```
name1.fits data1[1] err1[1] data1[2] err1[2] data1[3] err1[3]...
name2.fits data1[1] err1[1] data1[2] err1[2] data1[3] err1[3]...
```

So the next file would be

```
name1.fits data2[1] err2[1] data2[2] err2[2] data2[3] err2[3]...
name2.fits data2[1] err2[1] data2[2] err2[2] data2[3] err2[3]...
```

Then the first new file of my data would look like:

```
n1_Cam_A_120213_O.fits 4101.77  0.03223 1.     0. -3.5612  0.05278 3.561 0.05278 -0.278635 0.00237 4.707   0.4393  6.448 0.4125
n1_Cam_B_120213_O.fits 4101.767 0.0293  0.9999 0. -4.57791 0.03447 4.578 0.03447 -0.388646 0.00243 0.03091 0.00873 7.499 0.07529
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
with open('file.dat','r') as data, open('names.txt', 'a') as nam, open('values.txt', 'a') as val, open('errors.txt', 'a') as err:
    for lines in data.readlines():
        cols = lines.split()    
        if "fits" in lines:
            header = lines.split()
            nam.write(header[3])
        elif float(cols[0]) > 1:
            #print cols[0]
            x=str(cols)        
            val.write(x)
        elif float(cols[0]) < 1:
            #print cols[0]
            y=str(cols)
            err.write(y)
```

I'm just starting with python. I thought in separate name values and errors in different files and then select the rows and columns that I need. But since I'll be dealing with hundreds of rows and files, I would like a more automatic approach. What I want is to read the first 3 rows and write file1, then rows 1,4,5 and write file2, then rows 1,6,7 and write file3, then rows 1,8,9 and write file4, then skip blank row and read rows 11,12,13, and write file1, then rows 11,14,15 and write file2, and so forth (or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, is it what you need?

The result naming scheme is 0, 1, 2, ...

```
first = False
for i in open('file.dat'):
    i = i.strip()
    if not i:
        continue

    if 'fits' in i:
        name = i.split()[3][1:-2]
        data = None
        first = not first
        if first:
            out = []

        cur = -1
    else:
        if not data:
            data = i.split()
            if first:
                out.append(open('%d' % len(out), 'w'))
            else:
                cur += 1

            out[cur].write(name)
        else:
            for d, e in zip(data, i.split()):
                out[cur].write(' %s %s' % (d, e))

            out[cur].write('\n')
            data = None
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Perhaps I'm missing something but the files it generates are empty. I'm kind of lost with your code, I'll take a deeper look at it.

Comment: I'm still getting empty outputs. Do you get something different with the code as it is?

Comment: It generate new files: 0, 1, 2, 3

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get it to works, but perhaps you could give me some tips to get it better. Here it is:

```
with open('file.log','r') as data, open('out1.txt', 'w') as out1, open('out2.txt', 'w') as out2:


    def readError(error): # original data had errors inside parenthesis
        newError = []
        for e in error:
            e = e.replace('(','').replace(')','')            
            e = e.split()
            newError.extend(e)
        return newError

    for lines in open('file.log','r'):    
        lines = data.readline()
        cols = lines.strip().split()    
        if "fits" in lines:   
            name = cols[3].replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(':','') + ' ' + '0' + ' ' + '1'
            # 0 and 1 were some indexes I needed to add to each line

            for i in range(0,2):   # I needed to write 2 files
                dato = data.readline().strip().split()
                error_dato = readError(data.readline().strip().split())
                newline = ''
                if i == 0:
                    newline = name
                    for j in range(0, 7):   # data had 7 columns
                        newline = newline + ' ' + dato[j] + ' ' + error_dato[j]
                    print newline
                    out1.write(newline + '\n')
                elif i == 1:
                    newline = name
                    for j in range(0, 7):   
                        newline = newline + ' ' + dato[j] + ' ' + error_dato[j]
                    print newline   
                    out2.write(newline + '\n')

        linea   = data.readline().strip()   
        # I don't know why the code doesn't work without this line
```